# Importing Custom Fonts Flask and Tailwind CSS

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, tailwind-css

I am working on a web application using Flask and Tailwind CSS and can’t import custom fonts. I can build the CSS file but the HTML template isn’t showing the font. How do I get my custom font to import?

I have this in my CSS build file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Grifter';
    src: url(../../static/Skyer-Regular.otf);
}
```

Here is a sample of when I try to use my imported font:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=’mainStyles.css') }}"/>
</head>

<body class = 'bg-black'>      
<div class = "font-pri text-3xl text-center text-white">
Sample Text
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: why don't you just use href="name"?

Comment: I already tried href="name" but that didn't work. It's Flask so you have to use url_for

Comment: you would have to get the pathname right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact problem a while ago and have a solution that works. I ended up having to link a separate CSS file to each HTML template. Here is an example of what I did. I have my custom font and CSS file in my static folder. gameStyles.css is my Tailwind CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='gameStyles.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles2.css') }}"/>
```

Here is an example of what I would put in styles2.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'reg';
    src: url(../static/ObjectSans-Regular.otf);
}

body {
    font-family: 'reg';
}
```

I tried everything and this was the only thing that worked for me. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: If it works it works, but isn't that really tedious? Why not use generic css?

Comment: Because tailwind CSS makes doing the design really simple. I also started the application using tailwind without knowing I would run into this issue. Herby likely had the same problem